# Installing RKernel

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

Despite all my efforts, I wasn't able to install the R kernel for my IPython/Jupyter notebook on Canopy.

I've closely followed the clear instructions given in:
http://www.michaelpacer.com/maths/r-kernel-for-ipython-notebook
(or, alternatively, http://irkernel.github.io/installation/)

All goes well until the last step that install the kernel on Jupyter:

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Here is the weird message I get:

```
File "/Users/julien/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/jupyter-kernelspec", line 8
from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp.launch_instance
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My configuration is the following:

- Macbook with El Capitan
- R version 3.2.2
- IPython 4.0.1
- Jupyter 4.0.6

Comment: Your `jupyter-kernelspec` file is wrong it should say `from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp`. Remove all and reinstall, if it persist contact Canopy. Michael blog start to date also.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the file "jupyter-kernelspec " was corrupted for some reason. I replaced it by the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp
def main():
    KernelSpecApp.launch_instance()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It solved my issue.

Julien