# install R kernel into Jupyter from Canopy Python 2.7

Tags: r, python-2.7, jupyter

I am trying to install R kernel into Jupyter. After following the instructions in https://irkernel.github.io/installation/, I get the following error message. I use Enthought Canopy and Python 2.7. I have R installed and working independently.

```
>IRkernel::installspec()
  File "/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/jupyter-kernelspec", line 8
    from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp.launch_instance
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code in the call to installspec was incorrect. Open the file in your folder with XCode and edit as below. Close the file. Re-run the command in the Terminal. 
The original file reads as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp.launch_instance

    sys.exit(KernelSpecApp.launch_instance())
```

It ought to read...

Thanks to [Installing RKernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420680/installing-rkernel) for clarification. I am reposting with a more specific heading.