# %R magic no longer works in IPython or Jupyter following update to Canopy Ver 1.7.4.3348

Tags: r, enthought, ipython-magic, jupyter-irkernel

Previously %R and %%R magics were working in IPython and Jupyter python notebooks.
The R terminal version is:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

After upgrading to Version 1.7.4.3348 in Enthought Canopy, the notebooks and IPython no longer work. I have tried reinstalling following [Installing RKernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420680/installing-rkernel) and http://irkernel.github.io/installation/, which worked before. I run the command to load the R-extension as per

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

I get the error message as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-691c6d73b073> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'load_ext rpy2.ipython')

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2161         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2162         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2163         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2164 
   2165     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2082                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2083             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2084                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2085             return result
   2086 

<decorator-gen-64> in load_ext(self, module_str)

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.pyc in load_ext(self, module_str)
     64         if not module_str:
     65             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 66         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     67 
     68         if res == 'already loaded':

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.pyc in load_extension(self, module_str)
     82             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     83                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 84                     __import__(module_str)
     85             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
     86             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .rmagic import load_ipython_extension

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in <module>()
     57 template_converter = ro.conversion.converter
     58 try:
---> 59     from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri as baseconversion
     60     template_converter = template_converter + baseconversion.converter
     61 except ImportError:

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py in <module>()
      7                              INTSXP)
      8 
----> 9 from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame as PandasDataFrame
     10 from pandas.core.series import Series as PandasSeries
     11 from pandas.core.index import Index as PandasIndex

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat.numpy_compat import *
     23 
     24 try:

/Users/Llewelyn_home/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy_compat.py in <module>()
     13 
     14 # numpy versioning
---> 15 _np_version = np.version.short_version
     16 _np_version_under1p8 = LooseVersion(_np_version) < '1.8'
     17 _np_version_under1p9 = LooseVersion(_np_version) < '1.9'

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
```

Could it be related to Canopy version of numpy being listed as 1.10.4-1 and the np.**version** result being 1.11.1 (based on error message)? Any suggestions gratefully received. PS. R works in the console still, plus in terminal and in Jupyter with an R kernel...

Comment: Both numpy 1.10.4 and 1.11.1 have the `version` attribute, so I don't think that is the issue. Can you submit a bug report through Canopy's Help menu so that we can get more information regarding your system's configuration?

Comment: Done, thank you. I'm just puzzled why it works everywhere else, but not in that one environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support crew at Enthought examined the version of numpy, then pandas. Reinstalling both did not solve the problem. The unexplained resolution occurred from the `pip install theano --upgrade` command on the Canopy Terminal. Logging this error as an unexplained issue with %R but with the strong indication that it is about dependency version.